# Jsession ID and AdminConsoleSessionId in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

I deployed a shopping cart application in the Weblogic Cluster, which contain 2 managed servers in it.In weblogic.xml, i included the followig arugments:

```
**<!-- Insert session descriptor element here -->
<session-descriptor>
  <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
</session-descriptor>**
```

to replicate item purchased in the shopping cart.My Doubt is, when i'm tracking the request ID using firebug tool.I'm seeing two different request ID for each managed server.

**Request 1: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9003/shoppingcart/viewshoppingcart**
**Request 2: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9004/shoppingcart/viewshoppingcart**

- Request one Header:

Host    1xx.xx.xx.xx:9003
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  **ADMINCONSOLESESSION=5183QZ1Mjy12hZR21cW6CbVyfRj5yh0NThfXJQ2TlkyM0Fv6BJlx!42613329; JSESSIONID=G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!-1346249615!1012537584**

- Request two Header:

Host    xx.xx.xx.xx:9004
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  **ADMINCONSOLESESSION=5183QZ1Mjy12hZR21cW6CbVyfRj5yh0NThfXJQ2TlkyM0Fv6BJlx!42613329; JSESSIONID=G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!1012537584!-1346249615**
Cache-Control   max-age=0

In both header the JSESSIONID is different but ADMINCONSOLESESSION ID is same.

What is this ADMINCONSOLESESSION ID means?And Why i'm getting different JSESSION ID?

Example:

JSESSIONID=G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!-1346249615!1012537584
JSESSIONID=G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!1012537584!-1346249615

And in this session ID why this lost part of it alone modified ?Is there any format is available for JSESSIONID?

1346249615!1012537584 and 1012537584!-1346249615

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ADMINCONSOLESESSION** is the cookie name for the WebLogic console.

> The **format** of a session cookie is:
>
> - sessionid!primary_server_id!secondary_server_id

In my opinion the jsession ids you posted shows a proper behavior of your session replication mechanism.

The **sessionid** part is the same in both jsessionids as expected.

Initially the JSESSIONID is G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!**-1346249615!1012537584** which shows that the primary host server id is **-1346249615** and the secondary host server id is **1012537584**.

After the session is replicated the JSESSIONID is G130QZ8P7fhstLQvFs111J2XXpn33JMsvRF7tT1zpqfYwnXSKBPH!**1012537584!-1346249615** which shows that the primary server host id is **1012537584** and the secondary host is **-1346249615**.

Let's suppose that the id **-1346249615** belongs to **managed server A** and **1012537584** belongs to **managed server B**. Initially your requests to the server were serviced from the managed server A and after the session replication they were serviced from managed server B.

I hope this helps.